# CMake builds library without needing target_link_libraries for dependencies (wxWidgets in the case)

Tags: cmake, build, wxwidgets

Below is a working CMakeLists.txt, the application simply display a wxWidget frame.
If `target_link_libraries` is removed, it'll fail to be built.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TestCMake LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_definitions(-DBOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_CONCEPTS)

set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "-d")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED core base)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
include_directories(.
                    ..
                    ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE header_files *.h)
file(GLOB_RECURSE source_files *.cpp)

add_executable(TestCMake ${header_files} ${source_files})
target_link_libraries(TestCMake ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Now change the last two lines, it becomes as below.
No `target_link_libraries`, but it can be built succesfully, why?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(TestCMake LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_definitions(-DBOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_CONCEPTS)

set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "-d")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED core base)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
include_directories(.
                    ..
                    ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE header_files *.h)
file(GLOB_RECURSE source_files *.cpp)

add_library(TestCMake ${header_files} ${source_files})
```

Comment: The executable (created with `add_executable`) is failed to built because of `undefined reference` error is emitted by the linker. By default, `add_library` creates STATIC library. Creation of a static library doesn't involve *linking* step, so you want get "undefined reference" when created the library. But the error will be emitted when (in the future) you link your library to the executable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, "Creation of a static library doesn't involve linking step", not "Creation of a shared library doesn't involve linking step"?

Comment: Creation of SHARED library involves *compiling* and *linking* steps. Creation of STATIC library involves *compiling* and *archiving* steps. An *archiving* step doesn't call a linker.